# Vim autocompletion: "Pattern not found"

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am using vim with snipmate and youcompleteme. I have configured it as follows:

```
imap hh <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger=""
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
```

All my snippets are located in `~/.vim/snippets/...`. When I type in a snippet, I can see that vim recognizes it like this:

[image]

How ever, when I type `hh` to load the snippet I get this error:

[image]

What is wrong with my settings?

Many thanks

Comment: You say "I am using vim with ultisnips" but you have "imap hh <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger". Something is not right.

Comment: sorry, jsut fixed this